# Need Help Identifying the Issue with 'Include' and 'ThenInclude'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm seeking assistance in identifying and resolving an issue related to the usage of the Include and ThenInclude statements in my code. Specifically, I have encountered difficulties while working with these statements and would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance.

```
// Load all pump types along with their pumps.
var allpumpTypes = hydraulicOptionsContext.PumpTypeVariants
    .Include(pt => pt.PumpVariantCollection)
        .ThenInclude(pv => pv.Manufacturer.PumpVariants)
    .Include(pt => pt.OptionCircuitTypeCollection)
        .ThenInclude(oct => oct.OptionPropertiesCollection)
    .Include(pt => pt.OptionCircuitTypeCollection)
        .ThenInclude(oct => oct.PumpTypeCollection)
    .Include(pt => pt.OptionCircuitTypeCollection)
        .ThenInclude(oct => oct.Option.CircuitTypeCollection)
    .Include(pt => pt.OptionCircuitTypeCollection)
        .ThenInclude(oct => oct.Option.OptionName)
    .Include(pt => pt.OptionCircuitTypeCollection)
        .ThenInclude(oct => oct.Option.Specification)
    .Include(pt => pt.OptionPropertiesCollection)
        .ThenInclude(opc => opc.OptionCircuitType)
            .ThenInclude(oct => oct.Option)
    .Include(pt => pt.OptionPropertiesCollection)
        .ThenInclude(opc => opc.OptionCircuitType)
            .ThenInclude(oct => oct.PumpTypeCollection)
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .AsNoTracking();
```

It seems to be a potential issue with cyclic relationships in the Include and ThenInclude statements and I don't know where it's that cyclic problem. Could you help me to find it?

I tried to review the code logic: Examine the purpose of the Include and ThenInclude statements to understand their intended functionality and heck the database schema: Confirm that the relationships between entities and navigation properties in the database schema align with the Include and ThenInclude statements.

Comment: You haven't actually described the problem. Also, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Your code should be as simple as possible to fully demonstrate the issue. I doubt that you need all those `Include` calls to do that.

Comment: It's still not clear which issue you're facing. Does the query throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that Include references the original table (`PumpTypeVariants`) regardless of where it is placed in the chain, while ThenInclude references the last table included.

You are including `OptionPropertiesCollection` under `OptionCircuitTypeCollection` and under `PumpTypeVariants`. Maybe the last two Includes should be ThenIncludes under `OptionPropertiesCollection`?

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working :( @IAmCoder